# How to get the youtube banner or username for a youtube playlists using playlist id?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How do we get the youtube username or userid from a youtube playlist id using api.
Or would like to know how to get the playlist Banner image from the playlist id.

Comment: Do you want to get this from a generic user or from the authenticated user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the playlist banner image directly by making a HTTP request using [Youtube Data Playlist API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists).
The sample below will give you a JSON response which contains the banner image url and the `channelId` of the owner of the playlist.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id={PLAYLIST_ID}&fields=items%2Fsnippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The channelId that is obtained can be used to extract the username now using the [Youtube Data Channel API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels).

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&id={CHANNEL_ID}&fields=items%2FbrandingSettings&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```